# TYPO3 Extbase bidirectional 1:n relation

Tags: typo3, extbase

Let's say we have a 1:n relation between an `Author` and `Book` model. Modeling the relation using the Extension Builder, the necessary code to get `Book`'s for an author is provided.

But what about the **inverse**? How do I get the `Author` for a given `Book` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have created the following domain model with the Extension Builder.

[image: Domain model built with Extension Builder]

When you create a 1:n relation between Author and Book, the resulting database table for Book will contain a field which holds the UID of the author. To make use of this field, you have to add a **getter** in your book domain model to return the corresponding author for the given book.

Add the following to your domain model for book:

```
/**
 * Returns the author
 *
 * @var \TYPO3\YourExtension\Domain\Model\Author
 */
protected $author;

/**
 * @return \TYPO3\YourExtension\Domain\Model\Author
 */
public function getAuthor() {
    return $this->author;
}
```

Now you can use the new getter in Fluid to return the author of a given book with  `{book.author}`

Comment: I didn't even think about this quite logic approach. Somehow TYPO3 brought me to the point, where I do not try the logic way anymore ;-) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can add n:1 relation to Book model, then Extension builder will create getter and setter automatically..