# TYPO3 Extbase bidirectional 1:n relation - returns null

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I have a 1:n relation between two model objects: `MainAuthor` and `Book`. I created my domain model with the Extension Builder and I need to get the `MainAuthor` in the `Book` class, just like this: [TYPO3 Extbase bidirectional 1:n relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017525/typo3-extbase-bidirectional-1n-relation)

I followed the instructions, but `book->getMainAuthor()` returns null. Is there something else I should do?

Answer (score 0):

- Did you name your property correctly in `Book` (should be `$mainAuthor`)?
- Did you empty your caches?